# PHP: $_SESSION destroyed after page reload or refresh

Tags: php, session

My session is not working correctly, its unset after when I reload the url, but not when I refresh the page using browser refresh button, it sent again form information to browser , says **Confirm Form Resubmission** and session still remain, but when I press enter in the browser url, the session gone.

here is my Code

**UPDATED and complete php fil code**

```
<?php session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
require_once 'protect.php';
$logout = $_GET['logout'];

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script><script> google.load("jquery",'1.7'); google.load("jqueryui", "1"); </script>
<script src="js/mutate/mutate.events.js"></script>
<script src="js/mutate/mutate.min.js"></script>


<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.min.css">
<script src="js/signinout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/send_message.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/refresh_message_log.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
$('.main').mutate('scrollHeight', function(el) {
        expanded = false;
        $('#scrollHeight').text('scrollHeight changed:' + $('.main').prop("scrollHeight"));
        $('.main').stop().animate({scrollTop:$('.main')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
    });
})

function logout() {
    window.location.href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/onlinearn/chat/adminChat.php?logout=admin";
};
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Live Chat</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if ($_POST['signIn']) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
require_once 'cn.php';
    if ($username) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($cn,$query);
        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($numrows == 1) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $dbId = $row['id'];
            $dbadmin = $row['username'];
            if ($username == $dbadmin) {
                $_SESSION['adminid'] = $dbId;
                $_SESSION['admin'] = $dbadmin;
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'No user found.';
        }
        $AdminId = $_SESSION['adminid'];
        $Admin = $_SESSION['admin'];
        $welcome =  'Welcome <span id="loggedUser">'.$Admin.'</span>!';
    }


}
if ($logout == 'admin') {
    //session_destroy();

}
?>
    <div class="chatBox">
        <div class="user">
        <div class="chatlogo">Admin Chat</div>
        <?php if (!$Admin && !$AdminId):?>
        <form name="SignIn" id="signInForm" action="./adminChat.php" method="post" onSubmit="">
            <span class="error animated">Invalid uername</span>

            <input name="username" type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter username" size="13px" onClick='document.username.value = "" '>
            <input name="signIn" type="submit" id="signIn" value="SING IN">
            <?php else:?>
            <form action="signout_delete_content.php" method="post" onSubmit="">
            <span class="welcome"><?php echo $welcome;?></span>
            <input type="submit" value="SIGN OUT" id="signOut" onClick="logout()">
            </form>

        </form>
         <?php endif;?>   
        </div>
        <div class="main" id="result">
        </div>
        <div class="messageBox">
        <?php if (!$AdminId && !$Admin):?>
            <form name="messageBoxSignInForm" id="messageBoxSignInForm" onSubmit="return false">
            <input type="submit" id="messageBoxSignIn" value="Sign In to Enter Chat">
            </form>
            <?php else:?>
          <form name="newMessage" class="newMessage" action="" onSubmit="return false">
            <textarea name="newMessageContent" id="newMessageContent" placeholder="Enter your message here.">Enter your message here</textarea>
            <input type="submit" id="newMessageSend" value="Send">
            <?php endif;?>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

if I put my this `$AdminId = $_SESSION['adminid'];
            $Admin = $_SESSION['admin'];` variables on the top of code with session_start()

the session isn't set on first time submit the form, you have to submit form again or just refresh the page.and also my `onClick="logout()"` not working. it has function,

```
function logout() {
   window.location.href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/onlinearn/chat/adminChat.php?logout=admin";
};
```

any one cane help me out in this situation?

any help would be appreciated.

many thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you confirming what's in the session? Is there some more code involved here that you didn't post? I can see some echo statements that may fire when the form submits, but there's nothing in there that echos if there's no post data.

Comment: just see with more carefully, it has

Comment: Your `$welcome` variable is only set on post. Maybe this is what you are missing?

Comment: nope, just see be more carefully

Comment: Obviously I am having a hard time understanding you, and don't understand what you seem to be missing from the page. Telling me to "look more carefully" is not constructive.

Comment: ok, sorry for this, my apologies. I didn't meant to say.

Comment: Have you tried to store user information in a cookie, and check the cookie against the sesssion ?

Comment: No , but check the session , it is working correctly.

Comment: what do you mean by "its unset after when I reload the url, but not when I refresh the page using browser refresh button"?

Comment: when I enter in the browser address url bar, and press enter, its unset, but not when I press browser refresh/reload button.

Comment: I know that, but what's the difference? It doesn't matter if you hit F5, reload button or click enter in the address bar. In every case a new request is made.

Comment: I really dont know myself.

Comment: should I post my complete php file code here? if yes then tell me if its hard to understand.

Comment: first of all, look carefully at your HTML code, especially around line <?php if (!$Admin && !$AdminId):?> you might have some cases where your form is not properly closed or another case of nested forms which is not recommended.

Comment: use Google and search for "php login script for beginners" to get a better understanding of how things should be done. don't be mad on the community ;)

Comment: So this is what I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress doesn't appear to call `session_start()` because it wants to be stateless and if `register_globals` is defined, it automatically destroys your `$_SESSION`

Read more here: http://www.thinkingoutloud.co.za/content/20091012/php_wordpress_and_session

Here you can find a plugin for WP which makes it possible to use session variables: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32646/how-to-use-my-own-custom-session-value-in-wordpress/72744#72744

Comment: I am not using it in WordPress, its in localhost, and the WordPress is not functional at the moment.

Comment: Sorry. Saw the logout-function and assumed it was WP. You could try setting a save path for session like `session_save_path('/home/example.com/sessions');` with `777` permission. Or you could try creating a new file just to test if sessions really isn't working or your logic is incorrect in your code above.

Comment: I changed the directory path, and its same as it was.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new file just to test sessions? Could look like this: `<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['test'] = "My sessions do work!"; if(isset($_SESSION['test'])){ echo $_SESSSION['test']; } else{ echo "My sessions are not working!"; } ?>` Then you can see if sessions are working with your local php configuration or if the code above contains errors.

Comment: my session is working correctly, because what conditions I applied are approved which seems that sessions are functional.like here

this means show this form if session is set.
`<?php if (!$AdminId && !$Admin):?>
            <form name="messageBoxSignInForm" id="messageBoxSignInForm" onSubmit="return false">
            <input type="submit" id="messageBoxSignIn" value="Sign In to Enter Chat">
            </form>`

and this works.

Comment: I tried your code in my another file and in same directory and its working perfectly. so whats the problem?

Comment: You could try putting all of your session declarations inside a `if(!isset($_SESSION['example'])){ $_SESSION['example'] = "example"; }` to make sure you're not overwriting your session variables.

Comment: `isset()` checks if the variable is set and returns a boolean, read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). So what you're doing is you're checking if the variable is set or not. If it's not set (declared) - you declare it. If it's already set (declared), do not change it. So when you set your session variable for the first time you wont overwrite it the second time you load the page.

Comment: If I put out my `$AdminId = $_SESSION['adminid'];$Admin = $_SESSION['admin'];` from `if ($username)` statement and put to top,

I have to submit form twice to login.
what is this matter?

Comment: OK now I have made some changes as you said, but why I have to submit the form twice,
why this happen?
Until I dont submit the form button again, or refresh the page. page doesnt logged in

Comment: and now the session is working correctly,
and I put my `$AdminId = $_SESSION['adminid'];$Admin = $_SESSION['admin'];` at the top of my code with session_start();.